# gradlew not parsing pom file returning build issue with html tags

Tags: html, gradle, tags, gradlew

I try to run command:

```
./gradlew build
```

but I get an error:

```
> Task :compileGroovy FAILED
```

which is caused by

```
The element type "hr" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</hr>".
```

The full error stack trace:

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':compileGroovy'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':compileClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve org.jenkins-ci.plugins:job-dsl-core:1.77.
     Required by:
         project :
      > Could not resolve org.jenkins-ci.plugins:job-dsl-core:1.77.
         > Could not parse POM http://repo.jenkins-ci.org/releases/org/jenkins-ci/plugins/job-dsl-core/1.77/job-dsl-core-1.77.pom
            > The element type "hr" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</hr>".
   > Could not resolve org.jenkins-ci.plugins:job-dsl-core:1.77.
     Required by:
         project : > com.github.cfpb:jenkins-automation:-SNAPSHOT:6302983551-1
      > Could not resolve org.jenkins-ci.plugins:job-dsl-core:1.77.
         > Could not parse POM http://repo.jenkins-ci.org/releases/org/jenkins-ci/plugins/job-dsl-core/1.77/job-dsl-core-1.77.pom
            > The element type "hr" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</hr>".
```

so, I looked into
`http://repo.jenkins-ci.org/releases/org/jenkins-ci/plugins/job-dsl-core/1.77/job-dsl-core-1.77.pom`

there is no closing hr tag but I think it is not required.

So, what may I have wrong so my ./gradlew command does not parse POM properly and recognize html tags properly?

EDIT:

changing

```
maven { url "http://repo.jenkins-ci.org/releases/" }
```

to

```
maven { url "https://repo.jenkins-ci.org/releases/" }
```

in `build.gradle` solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The insecure URL (`http://repo.jenkins-ci.org/releases/`) redirects to a secure URL (`https://repo.jenkins-ci.org/releases`)

Request:

```
    curl -i http://repo.jenkins-ci.org/releases/
```

Response:

```
    HTTP/1.1 308 Permanent Redirect
    Date: Mon, 21 Feb 2022 09:16:19 GMT
    Content-Type: text/html
    Content-Length: 164
    Connection: keep-alive
    Location: https://repo.jenkins-ci.org/releases
    X-Request-ID: 6d5c624d38658f746681c51fb6c50e36

    <html>
    <head><title>308 Permanent Redirect</title></head>
    <body>
    <center><h1>308 Permanent Redirect</h1></center>
    <hr><center>nginx</center>
    </body>
    </html>
```

It seems that gradle does not follow the redirect and tries to parse the html response. So, if you use `https` should be fine.
There is an [issue](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/6557) on github related to this.